# obtener Primer y Ultimo día del año en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo en Sql server siempre obtener el primer y ultimo dia del año.

Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir lo que has intentado? Gracias.

Comment: Hola sstan, probando probando e investigando sobre fechas encontre esto y funciona perfectamente, lo comparto

SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS FechaInicio
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS FechaFinal

Comment: Hola Jonathan. ¡Qué bien que hayas encontrado la solución! Para beneficio de otros, por favor comparte lo que has encontrado por medio de agregar una respuesta a tu propia pregunta en vez de simplemente dejarlo como un comentario debajo de tu pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Y para referencia futura, para este tipo de preguntas, aparte de tu duda, siempre incluye también lo que has intentado o investigado. Las preguntas son mejor recibidas si se nota que hubo esfuerzo de tu parte. ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español!

Answer (score 1):

Comparto el como Obtener el primer y ultimo día del año en SQLSERVER

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS FechaInicio
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS FechaFinal
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta consulta, la cual entrega como resultado el 1 de enero y el 31 de diciembre del presente año.

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS PrimerDia,
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) AS UltimoDia
```